# Optimality criterion for convex optimization problem when the feasible set is the polyhedral set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, polyhedra

Consider this specific **optimization problem**:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_0(x) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & f_i(x) \leq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
& & h_i(x) = 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, p.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $f_0(x)$ is **differentiable**, $X$ is the feasible set, $X$ is a **convex** set, and
$X$ = {$x$|$f_i(x)$ $\leq$ $0$, $i = 1, \ldots, m, h_i(x)$=$0$, $i$ = $1$,...,$p$}.

From the Convex Optimization book of Stephen Boyd, I **know** how to prove that:

$x$ is the optimal point if and only if $x \in X$ and $\nabla f_0(x)^T(y - x) \geq 0\text{ for all } y\in X$, $y \neq x$.

However, when X is a **polyhedral set**, I **know** that $x$ is the optimal point if and only if

min($\nabla f_0(x)^T(y - x)) = 0\text{ for all } y\in X$, $y \neq x$ , but I **don't know** how to prove it.

Comment: What variable is the $\min$ on the last line taken over??? I don't think that this result depends on $X$ being polyhedral.

Comment: Sorry, the variable is y. By the way, I found the problem in the exercise section of my textbook, so I think that might be true.

Comment: @copper.hat I think the polyhedral set is more specific than the convex set, which means  the result will be more specific

Comment: The last statement is just a restatement of the result you know how to prove. Note that if $y = x$ then the first order approximation is zero. Again, it has nothing to so with $X$ being polyhedral.

Comment: Sorry, y is not equal to x

Comment: Ok, let me ask again. What variable is the minimisation in the last sentence over?

Comment: it's y. Actually, I'm not sure if the problem is true, but you can give it a try.